# ASP.NET 5 - Using a Configuration Setting

Tags: asp.net, configuration

I am playing with ASP.NET 5. I am trying to understand the new configuration model. I have read several articles. However, I am still unsuccessful in loading a configuration setting. My `config.json` file looks like this:

```
{
    "App" : {
        "Info" : {
            "Version":"1.0.0",
            "ReleaseDate":"03-15-2015"
        }
    }
}
```

My `Startup.cs` file looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }

    public Startup()
    {
        Configuration = new Configuration()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json");
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseErrorPage();
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });

        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseWelcomePage();
    }
}
```

In one of my controllers, I have the following

**MyController.cs**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;

namespace MyOrg.MyApp
{
    public class MyController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet()]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var version = Configuration.Get("App:Info:Version");
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
        }
    }
}
```

When I start the app, I get an error that says:

```
error CS0103: The name 'Configuration' does not exist in the current context
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Roslyn.RoslynProjectReference.Load(IAssemblyLo
adContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(String name,
 IAssemblyLoadContext loadContext)
   at Microsoft.Framework.Runtime.Loader.ProjectAssemblyLoader.Load(String name)

   at kre.host.LoaderContainer.Load(String name)
   at kre.hosting.RuntimeBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__4(As
semblyName assemblyName)
   at kre.hosting.RuntimeBootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__7(Ob
ject sender, ResolveEventArgs a)
   at System.AppDomain.OnAssemblyResolveEvent(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String assemblyFullName)
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like I've followed the examples I've seen. Yet, I can figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When you get an error, you should state which line causes the error, rather than leaving it up to the answered to guess.

Comment: On a side note but related.  AddJsonFile is in 'Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json'.  You will have to add that to your project.son file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearly you want to access `Configuration` property in your `Startup` class. And the error method says it doesn't know what `Configuration` is. So you need a `using` statement or a fully qualified name. Also, you should avoid naming things the same thing as stuff found in the framework. Your `Startup` class has a `Configuration` property, but it also tries to use the [`Configuration`](https://github.com/aspnet/Configuration/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel/Configuration.cs) class `from Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel`. How confusing is that?

Your `Configure()` method in `Startup` needs a `using` statement or fully qualified name so it knows what the `Configuration` class is.

```
using Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel; //at the top of your class
Configuration = new Configuration(); //later in the code, we can access without fully qualifying name
```

or

```
Configuration = new Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Configuration();
```

In your controller, you may have a similar issue. Replace `MyOrg.MyApp.Startup` in the example below with whatever the namespace is for your `Startup` class.

```
using MyOrg.MyApp.Startup //at the top of your class
Startup.Configuration.Get("App:Info:Version"); //later in the code, we can access without fully qualifying name
```

or

```
 MyOrg.MyApp.Startup.Startup.Configuration.Get("App:Info:Version");
```

---

### Better way of doing things

That should be enough to get you started. However, accessing the `Startup` class to retrieve your configuration isn't ideal, because now your controller's action methods depend on having the Startup class there. That's not very unit testable. Ideally your controllers should be isolated from each other. You should define some sort of interface to hold the configuration info you want, then have the controller depend on that interface. When you're in your site, you'll respond with a class specific to the site's configuration. When unit testing, you can have tight control over the test values by using a different class.

```
interface ISiteConfig
{
    string Version {get; set;}
    DateTime ReleaseDate {get; set;}
}

public class SiteConfig : ISiteConfig
{
    public string Version {get; set;}
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get; set;}

    public SiteConfig()
    {
        var c = new Configuration()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json");
        Version = c.Get("App:Info:Version");
        ReleaseDate = c.Get("App:Info:ReleaseDate"); //may need to parse here
    }
}

public class TestConfig : ISiteConfig
{
    public string Version {get; set;}
    public DateTime ReleaseDate {get; set;}

    public TestConfig(string version, DateTime releaseDate)
    {
         Version = version;
         ReleaseDate = releaseDate;
    }
}
```

Then you'd use [Dependency Injection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext.aspx) to inject instances of your configuration into the Controller.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly ISiteConfig Config;

    public MyController(ISiteConfig config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }

    [HttpGet()]
    public HttpStatusCodeResult Index()
    {
        var version = Config.Version;
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }
}


public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(IBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseServices(services =>
        {
            ...
            // Set up the dependencies
            services.AddTransient<ISiteConfig, SiteConfig>();
            ...
        });
        ...
    }
}
```

Now you can more easily unit test your action methods, because your unit tests can use the `TestConfig` class while the site can use the `SiteConfig` class. And also if you want to change how your configuration is done, you don't have to replace strings in a bunch of different places. You'll have one class where you do so, the rest is strongly typed and easy to change without blowing up your application.

Your unit test might look like this:

```
//Arrange
var testConfig = new TestConfig("1.0", DateTime.Now );
var controller = new MyController(testConfig );  

//Act
var response = controller.Index();

//Assert
Assert.AreEqual(200, response.StatusCode);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, is this true? If it is, I can't believe it. How is this better than `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["keyName"]`? I understand that supporting additional config sources (i.e. json, xml, etc.) is nice, but accessing the values should be just as easy.

Comment: @user70192 What are you talking about? It is just as easy if you just create a `new Configuration().AddJsonFile("config.json").Get("key name");` The problem with that and the old way is that they're not easily unit testable. And being testable is important, it's why MVC stresses separation of concerns.

Comment: So, why not have a single class called `SiteConfig` that exposes a statically visible method called `Get` and `Get` dynamically pulls from either `config.json` or `config.test.json`?

Comment: @user70192 But what if you need to test the behavior with different configurations in multiple unit tests? Sure, for a simplified method that's just returning a version number you really don't need to unit test it. But it's mean to illustrate the overall point that action methods should not need to know about how things are implemented, their dependencies should be injected into them in order to function. When you write action methods for more complex use cases, you'll need to properly make use of dependency injection so you can test things in isolation.

Comment: Is it necessary to use .AddTransient for the dependency injection, or is .AddSingleton also an option? The configuration wouldn't change at runtime (I think), so I'd say .AddSingleton would be correct too. Am I right?

Comment: @ProgramRight you are probably correct. Did you try it and see?

Answer (score 0):

As of Beta 5 the accepted answer is no longer correct. There is no longer a Get method on IConfiguration. Also the way of constructing the configuration object is also changed.

The following code works on Beta 7:

```
// showing using statements here since this is new from Beta 5
using Microsoft.Dnx.Runtime; // renamed was Microsoft.Framework.Runtime
using Microsoft.Framework.Configuration; // renamed was Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel
// other using statements here

// Startup constructor. Note: now takes IApplicationEnvironment
// this is required in order to get base path
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddJsonFile("dbconfig.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();

        Configuration = builder.Build();
}

// property to hold configuration object created in constructor
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   // this will bind to an IOptions<AppSettings> instance
   // where AppSettings is a class you define that has a set of 
   // properties that match your configuration section loaded from the 
   // json file
   services.Configure<AppSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings"));

   // here I am loading a connection string from a json file and passing into an
   // new EF 6.x DB Context class
   services.AddInstance<TalentAgencyContainer>(new TalentAgencyContainer(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:TalentAgencyContainer"]));

        // Add MVC services to the services container.
        services.AddMvc();

}
```